# Problem with containers in combination with the remember button

Tags: qfield, null

I've been searching for a solution for days. I'm using QGIS 3.14.15 on Windows 10 and created a point layer to take points with QField. I created a container with several options. In QField the containers are only visible if a specific drop-down choice is taken. When I use the checkboxes to remember the information of the containers, but I'm choosing another drop-down field at the next point which not open the container, QField nevertheless saves the information in the point. So after the synchronization with GIS those informations are in the attribute table. Sure, it is possible just to enable the checkbox, but I want to provide mistakes cause I want to use the information from the attribute table.

So is there any possibility to set the information to `NULL`, if the wrong drop-down field is chosen without enabling the remember button?

I created a field called "Art", which has the the drop-down choices

```
1 "Vermessungspunkt"
2 "Trasse sichtbar" 
3 "schiessen" 
4 "Bohrung" 
5 "Hausanschluss" 
6 "KVZ" 
7 "Saeule" 
8 "Verbinder" 
9 "Ende"
```

Then I created two containers, which are only visible if `"Art" = 'Trasse sichtbar' OR "Art" = 'Ende'`.